# Why I am able to connect to Tomcat server using one network connection and not another?

Tags: tomcat, connection

At my work I have tow network connections, the first is WIFI and the second is wired connection.

Using the WIFI connection, I can connect to my tomcat manager by typing in my browser:

```
http://my.website.ip:8080
```

But using the wired connection, the browser is waiting and then give me an error message, server not responding time out problem.

Knowing that I do not have problem using any of both connections if I type:

```
http://my.website.ip
```

I have a page acknowledge me that tomcat server is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a programming question.

Have you checked that your wired connection forwards requests to Port 8080 and the answer?
Maybe connections for Port 8080 are blocked for any destinations for unknown reason.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, how can I check that?

Comment: I assume you have not configured a local firewall on your computer to block that, so maybe you should ask your network administrator, assuming you are in an office.